# All combinations from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

**Problem definition:**

- I have a dictionary with `N > 0` parameter lists as values and parameter names as keys.
- Each of the lists may be of a different length (e.g., `k > 0, l > 0, m > 0...`).
- My goal is to produce a unified list of tuples `[(a11, a21, a31, ...), (a12, a22, a32, ...), ..., (a1k, a2l, a3m, ...)]`, where each tuple is a set of length `N`, and containing corresponding parameter values.

**Example:**

Given the following parameter dictionary:

```
const_params_dict= dict(a=[-1, 1], b=[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], th=[0.5])
```

the desired output will be:

```
Out: [(-1, -5, 0.5), (-1, -4, 0.5), (-1, -3, 0.5), (-1, -2, 0.5), ..., (-1, 5, 0.5), 
      (1, -5, 0.5),  (1, -4, 0.5),  (1, -3, 0.5),  (1, -3, 0.5) , ..., (1, 5, 0.5)]
```

**Solution for a known value of lists (i.e. known `N`):**

I can think of a way to solve this problem for a known value of `N`, as shown in `Code 1`

**Code 1:**

```
[(a, b, th) for a in const_params_dict['a'] for b in const_params_dict['b'] for th in const_params_dict['th']]
```

which results in:

```
[(-1, -5, 0.5),
 (-1, -4, 0.5),
 (-1, -3, 0.5),
 (-1, -2, 0.5),
 (-1, -1, 0.5),
 (-1, 1, 0.5),
 (-1, 2, 0.5),
 (-1, 3, 0.5),
 (-1, 4, 0.5),
 (-1, 5, 0.5),
 (1, -5, 0.5),
 (1, -4, 0.5),
 (1, -3, 0.5),
 (1, -2, 0.5),
 (1, -1, 0.5),
 (1, 1, 0.5),
 (1, 2, 0.5),
 (1, 3, 0.5),
 (1, 4, 0.5),
 (1, 5, 0.5)]
```

**My question:**

How can I generalize this solution for an arbitrary value of `N` in the most elegant and efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function of itertools likewise:

```
from itertools import product
list(product(*const_params_dict.values()))
```